# mocha change Flow file path from node-red

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, node-red

I have a problem to implement a unit-test for a node-red node with mocha.

If i run my test with "$ sudo mocha -t 3000" node-red can't load the flow_user.json. Because the option '3000' from mocha is set as directory in the 'Flow file:' path.

```
node-opcua-client
✓ copy testfile 'flow/flows_user' (1509ms)
✓ run Node-Red  (1856ms)

Welcome to Node-RED
===================

22 Sep 14:13:03 - [info] Node-RED version: v0.11.1
22 Sep 14:13:03 - [info] Node.js  version: v0.12.3
22 Sep 14:13:03 - [info] Loading palette nodes
Warning : using memcpy : OK
FAST: using node-expat
22 Sep 14:13:04 - [warn] ------------------------------------------
22 Sep 14:13:04 - [warn] Failed to register 1 node type
22 Sep 14:13:04 - [warn] Run with -v for details
22 Sep 14:13:04 - [warn] ------------------------------------------
22 Sep 14:13:04 - [info] Settings file  : /usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-red/settings.js
22 Sep 14:13:04 - [info] User directory : /home/user/.node-red
22 Sep 14:13:04 - [info] Flows file : /home/user/.node-red/30000
22 Sep 14:13:04 - [info] Server now running at http://127.0.0.1:1880/
22 Sep 14:13:04 - [info] Creating new flow file
22 Sep 14:13:04 - [info] Starting flows
22 Sep 14:13:04 - [info] Started flows
```

In the 'test.js' i open node-red with

```
RED = require ('/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-red/red.js');
```

i this wrong?

thanks for your help

Comment: Note we have a unit test framework for nodes that avoids the need to run an entire Node-RED instance. Have a look at the node-red-nodes repo for examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to look at the Embedding Node-RED doc on the website here: http://nodered.org/docs/embedding.html

But basically you should be requiring node-red and then creating a settings object to pass in

```
var RED = require('node-red');
...
var server = http.createServer(app);
...
var settings = {
    httpAdminRoot:"/red",
    httpNodeRoot: "/api",
    userDir:"/home/nol/.nodered/",
    flowFile: "flow_user.json",
    functionGlobalContext: { }    // enables global context
};
...
RED.init(server,settings);
```